# Как получить минимальное и максимальное значения из бд?

Tags: java, база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте! Мое Java приложение отправляет запрос в бд и получает содержимое этой таблицы. Нужно , чтобы приложение вычисляло минимальное и максимальное значение из колонки id, и выводил все значение с этим id. Можно ли реализовать с помощью Java? Или же придется прибегать к php?

Comment: можно даже без использования Java, только SQL

Comment: > Можно ли реализовать с помощью Java? Или же придется прибегать к php?

Как-то вы ловко java и php в одном вопросе увязали )

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Думал что уже выхода нет :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@TheCoolKuid](/users/20671/thecoolkuid) минимальное значение id из таблицы `tbl_name`

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM tbl_name;
```

максимальное

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

[@Etki](/users/16095/etki) я упрощу ваш запрос!

```
SELECT MIN(id) as min,MAX(id) as max FROM tbl_name;
```